# "Missing compiler required member" in Windows CE project

Tags: c#, windows-ce, unsafe, compact-framework2.0

I'm trying to build a solution I downloaded from our companys SVN server. However I'm getting a weird error: "Missing compiler required member 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.UnsafeValueTypeAttribute..ctor'". The project that is causing the error is a DLL project.

All projects in the solution is being compiled against .NET CF 2.0. My IDE is VS2008.

The weird part is, that the other developers in the company can easily compile the solution without any problems.

What I have come up with is that there is a class inside the project that is failing to compile. It have a contructor that is defined as "static unsafe". Alot of the methods in this class is also defined as unsafe.

Do any of you have any idea on how to solve this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn.. I figured it out just as I had posted the question. It was the reference to mscorlib. I referenced the 2.0 version of the DLL, when it wanted the 3.5 version for some mysterious reason. Thank you all for looking anyway.